# how to implement Facebook like layout to show photos in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I want to show photos in my application like Faceook shows. Currently I have a recyclerview and the list of this recyclerview contains some images, textviews etc. In this list I want to add a GridView also to show images as the no of images may be more than 1, so I want to show them in Grid.

My whole layout is like how facebook shows news feeds, but I want to implement the same layout of photos as well.

Can anybody help me here, so that I can implement the same layout of photos also.

Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: Is there anything that you tried to achieve this?

Comment: provide an image of the layout you want to implement

Comment: I have updated code in my question. Please check it out. Thanks